# Step Counter in Android KitKat

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

Google, in Android KitKat (v.4.4.x), newly introduced `TYPE_STEP_COUNTER` and `TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR` and `Batched sensor events`.

Does anyone know if the newly introduced sensor is supported in all KitKat devices or only the new devices with specific hardware (e.g. Nexus 5, Moto X, etc)?Can we create a list with all supported devices? Can these new sensors be used in the Android v4.4 emulator if you feed **mock** sensory data?

Comment: I would assume it would work in all devices, since I am pretty sure it works with the accelerometer an that is how the step detection works. I would also assume, however, that accuracy is likely device dependent.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I found some posts around and the authors state that you need specific devices since it is hardware dependent.

Comment: Nope, not sure, just making the assumption based off of the documentation stating that TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR determines steps based on acceleration changes (which as far as I know are only really detected by the accelerometer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all KitKat devices will support these sensors from my understanding of the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html):

> Both step sensors are hardware dependent (Nexus 5 is the first device to support them), so you should check for availability with hasSystemFeature(), using the FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR and FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER constants.

Comment: Yes, I have read that. Do you know if you can use the emulator to test this newly introduced features?

Comment: So is there a separate accelerometer sensor for steps? Or are step sensors more advanced versions of basic accelerometers?

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is a little misleading.. it says accelerometer but definately seems device dependent.  I have an HTC one, a Nexus 5, and a Nexus 7 and only the Nexus 5 shows it as an available sensor type.  I am currently looking to see if there are any good ways of using the accelerometer in instances where the step detector is not available..  interesting post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324356/how-to-calculate-exact-foot-step-count-using-accelerometer-in-android

Comment: all the devices i mentioned above are all running kitkat