# Step sensor (Or an equivalent) on android 4.1

Tags: android, android-4.1-jelly-bean, pedometer

I am working on a project where one of the options is to use a the step sensor in an android phone to count steps. The phone i am using is the Samsung GT-S5310, running android Jelly Bean 4.1.2 (API 16). I have been looking into the API for the step detector (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) and have been playing around with the github project (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BatchStepSensor). But the step detector was implemented in API 19 and im having problems finding any documentation on building a pedometer with the current device i have. If anyone has any resources they could point me to or a good place to start, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to calculate exact foot step count using accelerometer in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324356/how-to-calculate-exact-foot-step-count-using-accelerometer-in-android)

Comment: you can use google step count api.